# How to change width\height of fabric.Path object? Params width\height in constructor don't work

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use fabric-js and try to pass width and height of fabric.Path via params in constructor like so:

```
const path = 'M16.2777 24.96C15.4876 26.3467 13.5124 26.3467 12.7223 24.96L0.27808 3.12C-0.512027 1.73333 0.475607 0 2.05582 0H26.9442C28.5244 0 29.512 1.73333 28.7219 3.12L16.2777 24.96Z';

const mapObject = new fabric.Path(path , {
  width: 30, //
  height: 30, //
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: '#c9c9c9',      
});
```

It works fine, but I can't affect to "image size". I pass different values but nothing changes.

Where am I wrong and how can I set size of fabric.Path object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path objects can be resized by changing the `scaleX` and `scaleY` values.

To achieve a specific width or height, you can also use the `scaleToWidth()` and `scaleToHeight()` methods.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html#scaleToHeight
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html#scaleToWidth

Comment: What if we just want to change one dimension? Both of these linked methods constrain the proportions of the path, while I only want to increase the path width.